# Can I launch pc without connecting all internal USB?

Tags: usb, cable, computer-building

today for the first time I upgraded my pc, but I have my first problem, I have 2 f_usb1 cables, but only 1 port, can I launch it with having one of them disconnected? One is 600v vw-1 khf, and second one is cbi tube.

Comment: "second one is cbi tube." - What?  USB isn't required for a motherboard to POST.

Comment: I'm kinda confused cos it's my very first time, I checked the cable and it goes to external USB, so it just means one of the front usb ports won't work? There is usb 2.0 and usb 3.0 at the front, I connected thd the 3.0 one, by saying the cbi tube I meant what it says on the cable

Comment: Please edit your question because it's currently not clear.

Comment: "so it just means one of the front usb ports won't work? " Yes.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer, connected only one, and I have 2 usb ports on the front panel, one of them just doesn't work, one is usb3 second is usb2, so i chose the usb3, thanks for the answer tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No USB ports are necessary for your system to POST.

It sounds as though your case supports more USB ports than your Mainboard has headers to connect. Connect the ones you want, leave the others disconnected, things should still work just fine except that the disconnected USB ports will be nonfunctiona.

Comment: Sorry for not answering, it is as you say, have 2 usb slots on front panek but only one port on motherboard, chose the faster one which is usb3 as the second slot was usb2, thanks for clarifying it, thought it might have some other functions

Comment: The USB type is defined by both the main board and the port. If the main board header is USB 2 then you'll only get USB 2 at the front panel port, even if you connect a USB 3 port to it.